# The coordinate map of a one-dimensional TVS is continuous

Tags: solution-verification, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a one-dimensional real Hausdorff [TVS](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Topological_vector_space#Definition). We fix $v \in E \setminus \{0_E\}$  and consider the linear map
$$ 
T: \mathbb R \to E, t \mapsto tv.
$$

To prove that any $n$-dimensional Hausdorff TVS is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, I would like to verify

> **Theorem** $T$ is a homeomorphism.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

It's clear that $T$ is bijective continuous. It remains to prove that its inverse
$$
T^{-1} : E \to \mathbb R, tv \mapsto t
$$
is continuous. We need the following result.

> **Lemma** Let $E$ be a (not necessarily Hausdorff) real TVS and $f:E \to \mathbb R$ linear. Then  $\ker f$ is closed [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345468/let-e-be-a-t-v-s-and-f-linear-the-hyperplane-x-in-e-mid-fx-alpha) $f$ is continuous [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345066/let-e-be-a-topological-vector-space-and-fe-to-mathbb-r-linear-then-f-i) $f$ is continuous at $0$.

By above **Lemma**, it suffices to prove that $\ker T^{-1} = \{0_E\}$ is closed. This is true because $E$ is Hausdorff. This completes the proof.